# Strong Markov property of Bessel processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, markov-process

I am thinking about the following:

If $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a  Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^3$, how can we show that the Bessel process (of order $3$) $(|B_t|)_{t \geq 0}$ has the strong Markov property? Any hints?

Comment: @Ian Three-dimensional space, not one-dimensional.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, we show that $(|B_t|)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Markov process (with respect to the canonical filtration of $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$):

Let $u \in \mathcal{B}_b$ be Borel-measurable and bounded. Using that $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has independent increments, we obtain

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(u(|B_{t+s}|) \mid \mathcal{F}_t) &= \mathbb{E}(u(|(B_{t+s}-B_t)+B_t|) \mid \mathcal{F}_t) \\ &= \mathbb{E}u(|B_s+y|) \bigg|_{y=B_t}. \tag{1} \end{align*}$$

If we denote by

$$p_s(x) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}} \exp \left(- \frac{|x|^2}{2s} \right)$$

the heat kernel, then we can rewrite $(1)$ in the following way:

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(u(|B_{t+s}|) \mid \mathcal{F}_t) &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} u(|z+y|) p_s(z) \, dz \bigg|_{y=B_t} \\ &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} u(|z|) p_s(z-y) \, dz \bigg|_{y=B_t} \\ &=: h(B_t). \end{align*}$$

The next step is to show that $h$ is rotational invariant, i.e. $h(y) = h(R \cdot y)$ for any rotation $R \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$. To this end, we note that by the rotational invariance of the Brownian motion

$$\begin{align*} h(Ry) &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} u(|z|) p_s(R^{-1} z-y) \, dz \\ &\stackrel{x := R^{-1}z}{=} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}  u(|x|) p_s(x-y) \, dx \\ &= h(y). \end{align*}$$
Consequently, $h$ is rotationally invariant and therefore there exists a function $H:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(y) = H(|y|)$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Thus

$$\mathbb{E}(u(|B_{t+s}|) \mid \mathcal{F}_t) = H(|B_t|), \tag{1}$$

i.e. $(|B_t|)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Markov process.

Since the process $(|B_t|)_{t \geq 0}$ has continuous sample paths, this implies that the process is a strong Markov process (see e.g. René Schilling, Lothar Partzsch: *Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes*, Theorem A.25).

**Remark:** The proof shows, in particular, that $(|B_t|)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Markov process with respect to the filtration

$$\mathcal{G}_t := \sigma(|B_s|; s \leq t).$$

This follows from the fact that $\mathcal{G}_t \subseteq \mathcal{F}_t$ and the tower property:

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(u(|B_{t+s}|) \mid \mathcal{G}_t) = \mathbb{E} \bigg[ \mathbb{E}(u(|B_{t+s}|) \mid \mathcal{F}_t) \mid \mathcal{G}_t \bigg] &\stackrel{(2)}{=} \mathbb{E}( H(|B_t|) \mid \mathcal{G}_t) \\ &= H(|B_t|); \end{align*}$$

hence,

$$\mathbb{E}(u(|B_{t+s}|) \mid \mathcal{G}_t)= \mathbb{E}(u(|B_{t+s}|) \mid |B_t|).$$

Comment: @ saz : a Markov process is not necessarily a strong Markov process, you have to show the property for all stopping times for this to be true, so you should add a little something to your so far nice proof. Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge You are absolutely right, I'll add a remark (since Brownian motion has continuous sample paths, this is a standard approximation procedure).

Comment: @Did Thanks. Should be fine now...

Comment: Seems so, yes...

Comment: @saz Can you give some details for your Remark? I have known $\mathbb E[u(|B_{s+t}|)\mid \mathcal F_s]=\mathbb E[u(|B_{s+t}|)\mid B_s]$. How to prove $\mathbb E[u(|B_{s+t}|)\mid \mathcal G_s]=\mathbb E[u(|B_{s+t}|)\mid |B_s|]$

Comment: @EricYau See my edited answer.

Comment: @saz Thanks for your reply. I doubt the existence of such $H$ you mentioned in $(2)$, cause it seems to suggest that $B_t$-measurable is equivalent to $|B_t|$-measurable

Comment: @EricYau No, it doesn't. The point is that $h$ is rotationally invariant; so for instance we can define $H(r) := h(r e_1)$ (with $e_1$ denoting the first unit vector), then $h(B_t) = H(|B_t|)$.

Comment: Had a last question: Theorem A.25 from Schilling, Partzsch's book says that every Markov process having Feller property and right-continuos sample paths is strongly Markov wrt $\mathcal{F}_{t+}$. Does this mean that every Markov process with continuous sample paths has Feller property?

Comment: Asking this question as Feller property is about the property of transition operators, whereas the continuity of sample path is the property of sample paths (sorry for tautology).

Comment: @Mushtandoid Why do you think that any Markov process with continuous sample paths has the Feller property....? The result in Schilling & Partzsch doesn't claim (or imply) this.

Comment: Because theorem A.25 in Schilling & Partzsch book says that Markov process having Feller property and right-continuos sample paths has strong Markov process. But above there is only a proof that $|B_t|$ is Markov with continuous sample paths. Thus, I tried to figure out where Feller property comes from. I am slightly confused

Comment: @Mushtandoid Ah, now I understand your question. The key point is the approximation procedure which is used in the proof of Theorem A.25 (i.e. to approximate a stopping time $\tau$  from above by a sequence of discrete stopping times $\tau_n$). If you imitate the proof and use that $H$ is continuous, you will see that it works fine.