# Is the reflected Brownian Motion a Markov process

Tags: brownian-motion, markov-process

Let $W$ be a Brownian Motion (BM). The reflected BM is defined by $X=|X_0+W|$.

We need to show that this process is a Markov process w.r.t. its natural filtration and we need to compute its transition function.

To obtain our result we need to calculate $P_\nu\{X_t\in B|\mathcal{F}_s^X\}$. For this, I think we need to condition further on $\mathcal{F}_s^W$. But I can not figure out the details.

Can anyone give me some help?

Comment: Is $W$ a one-dimensional BM?

Comment: @saz Yes, it is.

Comment: I see. Well, then have a look at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1192322/. The proof there is for dimension $d=3$, but the one-dimensional case is proved quite similar.

Comment: @saz I need to show that it is a Markov process w.r.t. its natural filtration and not to the canonical filtration of $(B_t)_t$ (what you did). The hint is to condition further on this filtration, but how can we then conclude it is a MP w.r.t. its natural filtration?

Comment: Since the natural filtraiton $\mathcal{F}_t^X$ of $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ satisfies $\mathcal{F}_t^X \subseteq \mathcal{F}_t^B$, it follows directly from the tower property that $(X_t,\mathcal{F}_t^X)$ is a Markov process if $(X_t,\mathcal{F}_t^B)$ is a Markov process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I will do it more formally.
Let $x,y\geq 0$ and $t,s\geq 0$ and $f_t(x,y)$ the density of the normal distribution with mean $x$ and variance $t$. We use that we know that for the Brownian Motion the Chapmann Kolmogorov equation is right.

$$g_{t+s}(x,y)=f_{t+s}(x,y)+f_{t+s}(-x,y)=\int_R f_t(z,y)f_s(x,z) + f_t(z,y)f_s(-x,z)dz\\
=\int_{R+} f_t(z,y)f_s(x,z) + f_t(z,y)f_s(-x,z)dz+\int_{R-} f_t(z,y)f_s(x,z) + f_t(z,y)f_s(-x,z)dz\\
=\int_{R+} f_t(z,y)f_s(x,z) + f_t(z,y)f_s(-x,z) + f_t(-z,y)f_s(x,-z) + f_t(-z,y)f_s(-x,-z) dz\\
=\int_{R+} (f_t(z,y)+ f_t(-z,y))*(f_s(x,z) + f_s(-x,z)) dz\\
=\int_{R+} g_t(z,y)g_s(x,z)dz$$

In the last equation I use the symmetrie of the density of the normal distribution, e.g.

$$f_t(-x,-y)=f_t(x,y)$$
und
$$f_t(-x,y)=f_t(x,-y)$$

The equation before this is a substitution.

Comment: this is the CK Equation

Comment: is this right??

Comment: Thanks! In the first equality there should be a $t+s$, and the 'last' equation is after your edit not the last one anymore. But it looks fine!

Comment: And how do you argument that this is enough to show? I mean why it is the kernel of the reflected brownian motion? We know only that there exist a unique markov process with the kernels. Why is this the reflected Brownian motion?

Comment: I do not use this. I use the comment of saz (then in one dimension) to get that the kernel is given by what you stated and then show that this is a kernel.

Comment: Sorry.. I don't really understand the comment of saz. Can you explain it to me in one dimension for me? It would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this. Show $$\begin{align}P_t (x,A) &{:=} \int_A g_t (x,y)dy \\
P_0 (x,A) &{:=} \delta_x (A), \end{align}$$
where $g_t$ density of the folded normal distribution, is a Markov kernel (Chapmann K. Equation, etc.).

Then you know there exists a unique Markov process. That's the reflected Brownian motion.

Have someone any comments? Is that enough?

---

Perhaps you have to show this too.

For all continuous and bounded functions $f$, $$E[f(|B(t+s)|)|F_s]=E[f(|B(t+s)|)|B_s].$$

But this should be $$E[f(|B(t+s)|)|F_s]=E[f(|B(s)+B (s+t)-B (s)|)|F_s]= E[f(|B(t+s)|)|B_s].$$

---

$$g_{t+s}(x,y)= f_{t+s}(x,y)+ f_{t+s}(x,-y)=\int_R...=\int_{R+} ... +\int_{R-}....=\int_{R+}...= Claim $$

Comment: Please format your answer in [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Ok. I did not know how it works

Comment: Now. I think its enough to show the markov Kernel proparties. Is it right?

Comment: Yes this is right, but why does it satisfies the Chapmann Kolmogorov then?

Comment: I wrote how it works at the end of the page.

Comment: @Fred22 I don' t understand the equality $E(f|B(t+s)-B(s)+B(s)| |F_s)= E(f(|B(t+s)|)|B_s).$

Comment: Ok, are you using freezing lemma and the fact that $f|B(t+s)|)$ is $F_s$ measurable?

Comment: No, I actually did not understand that equality. Could you explain it to me?